# AVD Error (Android Virtual Device emulator) While running sample project

Tags: android, intellij-idea, emulation, android-virtual-device

The error specifies as follow :
 Folder C:\Users\Ayan.android\avd\MyAvd0.avd is in the way. Use --force if you want to overwrite
I don't really understand what this error is stating, why it is happening, and what I can do to resolve.
It occurs right after I create an Android Virtual Device.
Also can someone explain to me what the Abi Type, SDcard, and Size option do in the Android Studio "Run" prompt?

Comment: post the error log from console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**CPU/ABI:** Here you can specify if you want your emulator to be hardware accelerated(fast: ***intel-atom***) or not(very slow: ***armeabi-v7a***).

**SDcard size:** Set the size of the virtual SDCard in your emulator. You need to set it to be able install applications.

Have you tried to delete the MyAvd0.avd file and creat a new virtual device?
Maybe it's a name conflict.
Try to create a new device with another name instead of *MyAvd*.

Comment: Perfect answer, crushing each part of my question like plastic cups :) Yes, of course it was the name conflict haha. I should have seen that. Perhaps it was because I did not have the mindset that a new virtual emulator was created every time i set to run

Comment: Haha, I'm glad I could crush all your plastic cups ;). Don't forget to download the **Intel HAXM** by the  *Android SDK manager* and install it manually. Even if the manager states it's installed, it's not (at least on a Win OS).You can find it here *<Android Studio Home>\ sdk\ extras\ intel\ Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager* In addition you have to install an **Intel x86 Intel Atom Image** for each API you would like to use with a hardware accelerated emulator.

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you fellow contributing human friend :P I will do as you say haha :) Happy holidays to you as well!